# Java Streams: Is the complexity of collecting a stream of long same as filtering it based on Set::contains?

Tags: java, performance, optimization, java-8, java-stream

I have an application which accepts employee ids as user input and then filters the employee list for matching ids. User input is supposed to be 3-4 ids and employee list is a few thousands.

I came up with the following 2 methods using Streams filter based on performance concerns.

**Method1**

> Motivation here is to not run filter for each employee, rather run it on the requested ids list  which is guaranteed to be very short.

```
private static Set<Long> identifyEmployees(CustomRequest request)
  List<Long> requestedIds = request.getRequestedIDs();                            
  if (!requestedIds.isEmpty()) {
      Set<Long> allEmployeeIds = 
              employeeInfoProvider
                .getEmployeeInfoList()  // returns List<EmployeeInfo>
                .stream()
                .map(EmployeeInfo::getEmpId)  // getEmpId() returns a Long
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());

      return requestedIds.stream().filter(allEmployeeIds::contains).collect(Collectors.toSet());         
  }
  return Collections.emptySet();
}
```

**Method2**

> Motivation here is to replace collect() in Method1 with a filter as complexity would be same. collect() here would actually be running on a very small number of elements.

```
private static Set<Long> identifyEmployees(CustomRequest request)
  Set<Long> requestedIds = request.getRequestedIDs()   // returns List<Long>
                          .stream()
                          .collect(Collectors.toSet());
  if (!requestedIds.isEmpty()) {
      return employeeInfoProvider
               .getEmployeeInfoList()  // returns List<EmployeeInfo>
               .stream()
               .map(EmployeeInfo::getEmpId)  // getEmpId() returns a Long
               .filter(requestedIds::contains)
               .collect(Collectors.toSet());
  }
  return Collections.emptySet();
}
```

Does Method2 perform as good as Method1? Or does Method1 perform better?

Comment: Your code would be simpler if `getEmployeeInfoList()` (or better named `getEmployeeInfoMap()`) returned `Map<Long, EmployeeInfo>`. Doing so would not likely increase its time complexity, but would make the approach here and elsewhere much cleaner and faster.

Comment: Thats correct. But lets just assume its a legacy code and is being referenced from a lot of places.

Comment: Even in your second method, you could still perform the `requestedIds.isEmpty()` check on the list, before converting it to a set, skipping that work when empty. Besides that, `Set<Long> requestedIds = new HashSet<>(request.getRequestedIDs());` is likely to be more efficient than going through the Stream API here. Generally, it seems you are expecting `getRequestedIDs()` to be much smaller than `getEmployeeInfoList()`, which makes the second approach preferable. Maybe, it would even pay off to handle the special case of a single requested id (that wouldn’t require a Set).

Comment: @Holger why is 2nd approach preferable for shorter ```getRequestIDs()``` list? Did you mean to say 1st approach instead?

Comment: When `getEmployeeInfoList()` is large, the first approach builds a large Set of all existing IDs, regardless of how small the number of requested IDs actually is. The second approach, on the other hand, builds the small set of requested IDs.

Answer (score 2):

I would expect Method2 to perform as good or better in all scenarios.

Collecting to an intermediate set adds allocation overhead.  It reduces the number of `requestedIds::contains` calls you have to do later *if* there are lots of duplicates, but even then, you're exchanging each `Set::add` call for a `Set::contains` call, each of which should be a small win.

Answer (score 0):

A potentially faster (not cleaner) option would be to return immediately when all the requestedIds have been detected, but I'm not sure whether it could be implemented with Stream API.

```java
private static Set<Long> identifyEmployees(CustomRequest request) {
    Set<Long> requestedIds = request.getRequestedIDs()   // returns List<Long>
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    Set<Long> result = new HashSet<>();
    if (!requestedIds.isEmpty()) {
        Iterator<EmployeeInfo> employees = employeeInfoProvider.getEmployeeInfoList().iterator();
        while (result.size() < requestedIds.size() && employees.hasNext()) {
            Long employeeId = employees.next().getEmpId();
            if (requestedIds.contains(employeeId)) {
                result.add(employeeId);
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

However, it makes sense only if `employeeInfoProvider.getEmployeeInfoList()` returns multiple duplicates of employees with the same IDs.  Otherwise, as mentioned above, the method2 is a better choice.

Comment: The whole point of filtering from all employees' list  is to vet the requested ids for invalid values. This solution won't come in handy in those cases. Otherwise, I could have simply proceeded with the provided list of ids without filtering. Moreover, this doesn't look like a clean approach and you also forgot to include the contains check.

Comment: @ankit3j, I fixed the missing `contains` check and the offered solution deals with a hypothetical case (which may not be true at all), when `employeeInfoProvider.getEmployeeInfoList()` returns duplicate employees like `[emp:id=1, emp:id=2, emp:id=3, emp:id=1, emp:id=3, emp:id=4, emp:id=2]` while `requestedIds = [1, 2]`- so as soon as all `requestedIds` are validated, there's no need to stream entire `employeeList`.